# Custom Lazy Load - IE9 Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, internet-explorer

I'm currently developing a basic image gallery that dynamically loads new images in the following order (on document.ready):

1. Uses an ajax call to get JSON which contains all the information needed to dynamically render images.
2. Iterates over the JSON object to create proper divs/img elements which are then appended to the page.

   ```
               $.ajax({
               url: '/wp-content/themes/base/library/ajax/posts-json.php',
               type: 'get',
               //dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data) {
                   // turn string response to JSON array
                   window.responseArray = JSON.parse(data);

                   window.lastPhotoIndex = 0;

                   // make sure there is a response
                   if (responseArray.length > 0) {
                       // get container
                       var container = document.getElementById("photos-container");
                       var ulElement = document.createElement('ul');
                       ulElement.className = "rig columns-3";
                       ulElement.setAttribute("id", "photo-list");

                       // iterate over each response
                       window.photoCount = 0;
                       for (var i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i += 1) {
                           // Only load first 10 images
                           if (responseArray[i]["post-type"] == "photo" && photoCount < 20) {
                               // Set the last photo index to this photo
                               lastPhotoIndex = i;
                               // create the li
                               var liElement = document.createElement("li");

                               liElement.className = liElement.className + responseArray[i]["day"];

                               //create class name string from WP tags
                               if (responseArray[i].tags.length > 0) {
                                   for (var ii = 0; ii < responseArray[i].tags.length; ii += 1) {
                                       nospaceTagName = responseArray[i].tags[ii].split(' ').join('');
                                       liElement.className += " " + nospaceTagName;
                                   }
                               }

                               //create image element and append to div
                               var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
                               imgTag.src = responseArray[i]["thumb-url"];
                               liElement.appendChild(imgTag);

                               //Add modal class info to outer div
                               liElement.className += " md-trigger";
                               //Add data-modal attribute to outer div
                               liElement.setAttribute("data-modal", "photo-modal");

                               ulElement.appendChild(liElement);

                               //next slide
                               photoCount++;
                           }
                       }
                       //append ul to container
                       container.appendChild(ulElement);
                   }
               },
               error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                   console.log(xhr);
                   console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
               }

           });// end ajax call
   ```
3. After the ajax call, I add a window scroll event that will be called while there are still more photos in the JSON object.

   ```
               // Window scroll event
           $(window).scroll(function () {
               var trigger = $(document).height() - 300;
               if (trigger <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                   //Call function to load next 10
                   loadNextPhotos();

               }
           });
   ```
4. The function called by the scroll even simply starts off at the previously left off index (lastPhotoIndex variable set at the beginning of ajax call - 'window.lastPhotoIndex'). The function looks like this:

   ```
   function loadNextPhotos() {
   if (photoCount < getPhotoCount()) {
       var photosOutput = 0;
       var startingIndex = lastPhotoIndex + 1;
       var photoList = $('#photo-list');
       for (var i = startingIndex; i < responseArray.length; i += 1) {
           if (responseArray[i]["post-type"] == "photo" && photosOutput < 10) {
               lastPhotoIndex = i;
               photosOutput++;
               // create the li needed
               var element = document.createElement("li");

               element.className = responseArray[i]["day"];

               //create class name string from tags
               if (responseArray[i].tags.length > 0) {
                   for (var ii = 0; ii < responseArray[i].tags.length; ii += 1) {
                       nospaceTagName = responseArray[i].tags[ii].split(' ').join('');
                       element.className = element.className + " " + nospaceTagName;
                   }
               }

               //create image element and append to li
               var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
               imgTag.src = responseArray[i]["thumb-url"];


               element.appendChild(imgTag);

               //Add modal class info to li
               element.className = element.className + " md-trigger";
               //Add data-modal attribute to outer div
               element.setAttribute("data-modal", "photo-modal");

               photoList.append(element);

               // Keep track of photo numbers so modal works for appropriate slide number
               photoCount++;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Bear in mind, this code is stripped down a lot from the full application. It works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE10+.

**When loaded in IE9, I'm experiencing crazy memory leaks as I hit the scroll event and append more items to the UL.**

My guess is that I'm not following best practices when creating new items to be appended and they're staying in memory longer than they should. The only issue is I'm not sure how to solve it/debug it because the page crashes so quickly in IE9.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've tried implementing Darmesh's solution with no real luck. As I said in his comment it only delays the rate at which memory is leaked. I've also added [jquery.visible.js](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/) on top of a scroll event so it looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if($('#lazy-load-trigger').visible() && window.isLoadingPhotos != true) {
    console.log("VISIBLE!");
    loadNextPhotos();
}
```

});

But it also only delays the memory leak. I still believe there are issues with Garbage Collection in IE9, but am not sure how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to the browser calling `loadNextPhotos` function multiple times at the same time every time you scroll. This might work, give it a try,

```
function loadNextPhotos() {
    // Add flag to indicate new photos adding started
    window.isLoadingPhotos = true;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    // Indicate new photos adding completed
    window.isLoadingPhotos = false;
}
```

And,

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var trigger = $(document).height() - 300;
    if (trigger <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        if(!window.isLoadingPhotos) {
            //Call function to load next 10
            loadNextPhotos();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this delays the speed at which the page freezes, I still seem to have a memory leak. I tried adding jquery.visible.js to help prevent the leak but still it only delays the rate at which it happens. See my update in the edit.

Comment: set `element` to `null` after `photoList.append(element);`, it appears that IE9 do not garbage collect DOM-object as DOM objects are not in the mark-and-sweep garbage collection scheme of JScript.